# Prove the differentiability of funtion $f(x)$ using the condition of $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(ax)}{x}=A$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

$f(x)$ is a continuous function, for some fixed $a\in(0,1)$ and some real number A satisfy
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(ax)}{x}=A$$
Prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and compute the value of $f'(0)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question is closed because an almost identical problem has already been discussed in this community. This does not mean that your question has an issue, so I hope that this does not discourage you from asking other questions in this community.